# Get data from multiple tables using one Mapping Table in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

**Procedure.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "procedures")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class Procedure implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ProcedureId")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ProcedureName")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "ProcedureCode")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "ProcedureDesc")
    private String desc;
//  getters and setters
}
```

**CPTClinicianDescriptor**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliniciandescriptor")
public class CPTClinicianDescriptor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ConceptId")
    private int conceptId;

    @Column(name = "CPTCode")
    private String cptCode;

    @Column(name = "ClinicianDescriptorId")
    private int clinicianDescriptorId;


    @Column(name = "ClinicianDescriptor")
    private String clinicianDescriptor;
//  getters and setters
}
```

**CPTProcedures**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cptprocedures")
public class CPTProcedures {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private int Id;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ProcedureId")
    private Procedure procedure;
    @Transient
    private int procedureId;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CPTCodeSet")
    private CPTClinicianDescriptor cptClinicianDescriptor;
    @Transient
    private int cptCodeSet;
//  getters and setters
}
```

Here I have 3 table in mySql in those 2 are different separate tables, I created one table for Mapping that has foreign keys of Procedures and CPT when i get a list using Procedure It should get corresponding cpt data also.

**ServiceImpl** Like:

```
public List<Procedure> getCombinedProcedureList(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Procedure> pList = new ArrayList<Procedure>();
        Procedure procedureList = procedureRepository.findCombById(id);
        pList.add(procedureList);
        return pList;
    }
```

When i use
**Repository** like

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM procedures JOIN cliniciandescriptor ON cliniciandescriptor.Id  = ?1",nativeQuery = true)
Procedure findCombById(int id);
```

this query in Procedures Repository it is getting only procedures. So, what can i do to get the combined(joined) list of 2(procedures & CPT) tables using 3rd mapping table.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on exact requirements?

Comment: Hi, I have 3 tables, **Procedures,cliniciandescriptor,CPTProcedures**. I have Procedures's & ClinicianDesc's Primary keys as 2 foreign keys in CPTProcedures, when i write the list of CPTProcedures i'm getting whole data from procedures and cliniciandes, But I want to right the list for Procedures and i want to get the list of Procedures and corresponding ClinicianDescInfo which i map in CPTProcedure Table

Comment: Still unable to understand.

Comment: Return type is `Procedure`, so it is returning Procedures only. Checkout `SQLResultsetMapping` and do accordingly.
Checkout SQLResultsetMapping here:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping